# When To use async-storage and when to use redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

Is it fine to store information such as login as - guest, manager, staff , login id, or many more in Async storage to render UI according To to these value.

and when to use async and when to use redux. or if I manage our work with Async then Why I have to use redux. because as of now I do not know redux. so I am somehow manage my rendering By setting and getting values from async..

please help thanks.

Comment: You don't "have to" use redux...

Answer (score 2):

Both are different things Async storage stores your data permanently until you  uninstall the app while redux is useful for managing the state of your whole app and once you force close your app then redux will lost the state you have updated (You can persist the state with redux-persist along with AsyncStorage)

I will suggest use redux with redux-persist(Allow specific reducers to be persisted in AsyncStorage) so you can manage your state in better terms with ease of access by using selectors. Also with redux you can share data between your components/screens.

It will be hard to manage your json in Async Storage because you need to convert it to the string and also while fetching parse it which is  burden.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at **SecureStore**, this is safe place to hold data like login/password/tokens.

Use **AsyncStorage** to store data like theme/language. It's a data to use
on a currently used mobile. You can keep this data and the next time if you use the app you can use these settings.

Use **redux** to manage data like cars, animals etc. Sometimes you will need to get selected data on login if you don't need to get it every time. For example you get all animals on login, and when you go into animals view you have all animals without additional GET. You can do it on every time, when you go into this view only if are you sure that other user from another account don't update this data, you should do it every time when you navigate to this view.